# Can't get JavaScript file to load in script tag

Tags: javascript, html

I'm very new to JavaScript and HTML and have come across the problem where I cannot load a JavaScript file from my HTML within the script tag.
I'm not sure why this is happening and I haven't been able to find a tutorial or a question that is having my same problem. I've included the exact code of both files as well as the path to each file.

/webtest/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>

  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="/src/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

/webtest/src/main.js

```
document.write("Test")
```

The result of opening index.html in my browser is a blank white screen.

Comment: The most likely explanation is that the URL is wrong. Debug using the Netwrok tab of the browser's developer tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `src` url is wrong. It should be: `src/main.js` without the first `/`

When importing files in your webpage, if the url begins with a `/` it implies you would like to start at the root of the domain, eg. at `localhost/`.

If you immediately start with the directory or file with no `/`, it implies the file is relative to the current location eg. `localhost/my/current/page/`

Answer (score 0):

You should write the path of `main.js` as follows:

```
<script src="./src/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

In order to start from the main directory and then move forward.